# Changing font-color on keydown via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to move a circle around the screen via jQuery using wasd keys.  I have the code that can move the circle around the screen but I'm also trying to light up the keys when they are pressed.  I can't seem to get the light up code to work... any suggestions?  The color should only show for a short time once a user presses it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kUf5q/

here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        case 65:
            $('#box').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            $('span').css('color: red;');
            break;
        case 83:
            $('#box').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            $('span').css('color: red;');
            break;
        case 87:
            $('#box').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            $('span').css('color: red;');
            break;
        case 68:
            $('#box').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            $('span').css('color: red;');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: good once, can you please explain what do you mean by 'trying to light up the keys'

Comment: You are aware that your code fails when you keep an key on hold?

Answer (score 1):

Create an highlight function where `key` is the key that must be hightlight and `delay` the amount of time it must be highlighted.

```
var highlight = function(key, delay) {
    $('.button.' + key + ' span').css('color', 'red');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.button.' + key + ' span').css('color', 'white');
    }, delay);
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ELHQ2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
$("span").css('color','red');
```

or

```
$("span").attr("style","color:red;");
```

Also, note that this will change the color of all spans, consider using ids or classes to select them.

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom function for you to change color call `changeColor(className)`, here's how it works:

```
function changeColor(spanClass) {
    //Change the pressed key to "red"
    $("div." + spanClass + " span").css("color", "red");

    //After half-second, change it back to "white"
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("div." + spanClass + " span").css("color", "white");
    }, 500);
}
```

Now, each time you press a button, pass in the button being pressed:

```
case 65:
    $('#box').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    changeColor("a");
    break;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kUf5q/1/

Answer (score 0):

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UxxH6/)

```
  function chnage_bg_color(class_button) {
        $('.button.' + class_button).css('background-color', '#ccc').find('span').css('color','red');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.button.' + class_button).css('background-color', '#000').find('span').css('color','#fff');
        }, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working demo, it's simple, no extra methods, and also un-highlights on keyup.  By the way, this lights up the key itself, not the font of the character.

http://jsfiddle.net/EaQWd/23/

Add id to button div's:

```
            <div id="boxW" class="w button"><span>W</span></div>
            <div id="boxA" class="a button"><span>A</span></div>
            <div id="boxS" class="s button"><span>S</span></div>
            <div id="boxD" class="d button"><span>D</span></div>
```

Then use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            case 65:
                $('#box').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                $('#boxA').animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 83:
                $('#box').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                $('#boxS').animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 87:
                $('#box').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                $('#boxW').animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 68:
                $('#box').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                $('#boxD').animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 'fast');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            case 65:
                $('#boxA').animate({backgroundColor: "black"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 83:
                $('#boxS').animate({backgroundColor: "black"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 87:
                $('#boxW').animate({backgroundColor: "black"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 68:
                $('#boxD').animate({backgroundColor: "black"}, 'fast');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Also, had to add jquery-ui to make it work.  Hope this helps!